# Git Bash VIM Screw Up

Tags: git, bash, vim

I'm working on lab 3 of the Git Immersion tutorial and when I was trying to create a folder and a file called hello and hello.rb, respectively, I tried the command

```
$ vim hello.rb
```

and it took me to a screen with lots of tildas on the left side and a previous cd command call when I was trying to redirect to my Downloads folder. After hitting "." and "Backspace" a few times, more lines of previously executed code started popping up. I hit control z to luckily navigate back and now I see a

```
[1]+  Stopped                 vim hello.rb
```

What does this mean and what should I do to make sure I didn't screw up big time?

Comment: I can't type into the VIM screen, the pointer isn't even on a new line it is in the middle of a line and backspacing doesn't erase anything it simply moves the pointer back one spot, Escaping doesn't do anything besides pop up a ^[

Comment: The control-z put the Vim command in background. Bring it back to foreground with the command `fg`, and then exit Vim by first pressing Escape, and then type `:q!`

Comment: When you press `:`, you should see a line at the bottom of the window where you can type. Type `q!` and press enter. That should exit Vim.

Comment: It sounds like you're not familiar with the `vi` editor.  It is a very good editor - I use it quite a lot - but most people don't find it intuitive at first.  You may want to substitute a text editor with which you're familiar, unless you have the time to read up on how to work with `vi`.  (If you do decide to use a different editor, be sure to configure git accordingly.  `git config --global core.editor *command-to-invoke-your-editor*`)

Comment: I'm simply trying to learn Git but apparently creating a file within a folder is much tougher than I expected lol *hardcoding the .rb file would be cheating so I'm just going to stop

Comment: When using `git` cli interface it would be best to know how to use your `$EDITOR` and/or git's `core.editor`. In this case it is set to `vi`/`vim`. I would recommend changing your default editor to something you are more familiar with (`nano` maybe?). The other option would be to learn `vi`/`vim` which is a good skill to have if you are on a *nix environment. Run `vimtutor` to start your Vim journey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The control-z put the Vim command in background.
The output `[1]+  Stopped` means that the job is stopped (it can be resumed), and it's job number is 1.

If you want to exit the Vim process without saving anything,
you can kill it with:

```
kill -9 %1
```

And it seems you're not familiar with the Vim editor,
that's why you don't understand what you're looking at,
and how to exit from it.
If you want to use Vim, read some tutorials first.